# How can an amateur remove only the voices from a video on a Mac?

Tags: audio, video, imovie

I took a video in the mountains with my phone over the weekend. In the background there are others who are speaking during the video. I'd like to remove these voices but retain the sound of the wind and birdsong. Is this possible with [iMovie](https://www.apple.com/imovie/) and/or [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/), or perhaps some other free or inexpensive app?

Comment: Honestly, even for a trained editor using industry-standard equipment, this would be a difficult task. I'm not going to say you certainly can't do it, but it'll be an almost impossible task.

Comment: Might be easier to remove the audio track and add artificial wind and bird sounds

Comment: actually if you have places in the video where there is no talking and just ambient noise you can export the sound and load the audio into something like Audacity, splice it all together back to back (repeating where necessary) and lay it back over the audio track, effectively removing the voices... just a thought.